# Ambari rest api for services installation monitoring

Tags: installation, cluster-computing, monitoring

I'm facing with problem where I need via Ambari REST Api get progress of services installation. For cluster deploy I use Ambari Blueprint. Read logs is not a solution. Further I need write script which will print progress to cli.
Could you help with this issue?  Maybe you have some advices?

Comment: What have you written so far, and how is it deficient?

Comment: At this moment I have deployed cluster with ambari blueprint, everything is ok. And while cluster deployment is running I just need to monitor whole this process. I need some kind of notification when everything is ok.

Comment: That's a nice *description*, but if you want help with your script, you need to post, you know, the script.

Answer (score 4):

The response to the cluster creation call returns an href to a request instance which can be queried to get the status of the create cluster request.

```
202 - Accepted
{
    "href" : "http://c6401.ambari.apache.org:8080/api/v1/clusters/MyCluster/requests/1",
    "Requests" : {
        "id" : 1,
        "status" : "InProgress"
    }
}
```

More information can be found in the [asynchronous response section of the Ambari REST API docs](https://github.com/apache/ambari/blob/trunk/ambari-server/docs/api/v1/index.md#asynchronous-response).

Comment: Why the down vote?  All of the information that I provided was accurate and relevant.